# How to disable list types for Jodit Editor?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, jodit

I want to update my Jodit dependency to the latest version, but I want to disable the differnt list style types for ordered and unordered lists.
Is there any way how I can achive this?

In the old version, that I'm currently using I can simple select a ordered or an unordered list.
[image]

In the latest version there are differnt styles, but I only want `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>` without giving the user the option values to select e.g. "Lower Alpha" or "Lower Greek"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved it, by overwriting the config for `ul` `ol` controls.

```js
__Editor = new Jodit('#editor', {
        controls: {
            ul: {
                list: Jodit.atom({
                    default: 'Default'
                })
            },
            ol: {
                list: Jodit.atom({
                    default: 'Default'
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

`Jodit.atom` causes a replacment of the default values.
https://xdsoft.net/jodit/pro/docs/how-to/add-custom-font-family.md

You can find the default values in the plugin defintion file:
https://xdsoft.net/jodit/pro/docs/how-to/add-custom-font-family.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jodit [Playground](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/play.html) to disable the plugins. The ordered and unordered lists belong together and can be disabled this way:

```
var editor = new Jodit("#editor", {
  "disablePlugins": "ordered-list"
});
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: With this switch I can only disable lists totally, but It isn't possible to disable only the special styles options

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve that by passing `undefined` to the list. Found it by trial and error.

```js
{
  controls: {
    ul: {
      list: undefined
    },
    ol: {
      list: undefined
    },
  }
}
```